# javascript - .join method returns string joined by commas

Tags: javascript, arrays

The `.join` method used to solve the question returns string joined by commas.

[Question]-Repeat a given `string str` (first argument) for `num` times (second argument). Return an empty string if `num` is not a positive number. (The built-in `repeat()`-method should not be used)

```js
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
  // repeat after me
  return num > 0 ? str.split(" ").map(function(item) {
    let a = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      a.push(item);
    }
    return a;
  }).join("") : "";
}

console.log(repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3));
```

There are better ways to solve this using recursion or loops but why is the `.join("")` method returning string joined by commas?

[link to problem](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-algorithm-scripting/repeat-a-string-repeat-a-string)

Edit -

```
repeatStringNumTimes("*", 8);  
repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 4);
```

(these are the calls that cause the problem)

Comment: Because the `.join()` isn't actually doing anything useful and is operating on an array of length 1 containing an array of length `num`. I think you should go through your code and try to put into words what you think it's doing at each step. The use of `.split(" ")` makes no sense.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Comment: You say "There are better ways to solve this using recursion or loops", but you _are_ using a loop here. You've just wrapped the loop in a bunch of stuff that shouldn't be there and that's why you're having trouble.

Comment: @JLRishe I forgot to mention other function calls that are causing the problem and what I meant by saying better ways is using simple while loop to solve the problem. My concern was this code not doing the same(no matter how complex or bad the code is )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...but why is the .join("") method returning string joined by commas ?

Because the entries in the array you're returning from `map` are *arrays*, so you have an array of arrays. When you call `join` on an array, it implicitly uses `toString` on each entry of the array. The default `toString` on arrays uses `.join(",")`, so each inner array becomes a comma-delimited string (and then your outer `.join("")` combines those with no separator between).

Here's a simple example showing the same effect using `join("")` on an array of arrays:

```js
var arrayOfArrays = [
  ["one", "two", "three"],
  ["uno", "due", "tre"],
  ["un", "deux", "trois"]
];
console.log(arrayOfArrays.join(""));
```

---

`split` shouldn't be part of this solution at all. An array *could* be part of it if you like, but it certainly doesn't have to be. A simple `while` loop counting down `num` and doing string concatenation would be the simplest solution. (Lurkers: I'm intentionally *not* coding that for the OP, because the OP needs the opportunity to learn how to do it himself...)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it just be easier to use `.replaceAll(',', ' ')`?
That's what I usually do for stuff like this.

Below is the same code as above but just added `.replaceAll(',', ' ')` after the `.join`.

```js
var arrayOfArrays = [
  ["one", "two", "three"],
  ["uno", "due", "tre"],
  ["un", "deux", "trois"]
];
console.log(arrayOfArrays.join("").replaceAll(',', ' '));
```